# how to check cumulative usage in single transaction in debug logs

Tags: debugging

I can see many cumulative usage limit in debug logs.
Can we get entire transaction cumulative usage ?

What is the cumulative usage in the debug logs . For example if my trigger 4 times, each time does it have cumulative usage or how it works.
Need help on this

Comment: Just look at the last limit usage statements in the debug log?

Comment: I can see last limit usage is less than the usage in the middle